# How and why does this Cu change into C (graphite)?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

[image: Lithium-Ion accumulator]

<sub>Source: [gutefrage.net](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/chemie-lithium-ionen-akku---aufbau)</sub>

At the right side of the graphic, the Cu changes while discharging into C as graphite. How and why does this happen?

I thought it happens because of the dissolving of the Cu when the electrons stream from the Cu to the Al.

Answer (score 2):

The electrode in here has two parts – the Cu and the graphite (C). The Cu won't dissolve. Only the graphite (C) will react. So there is no changing from Cu to C.